# Regular Expression. Find integers only

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

Find only the integers in a math equation...

5 + 5.5 + 6 / 2.0

I want to find the 5 and the 6 not the 5.5 or the 2.0
To find decimals I use  \d+(.\d{1,})

I've tried \b\d+\b but that finds all the digits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind and lookahead, if that's supported by your regular expression engine. The regular expression would be:

```
(?<!\.)\d+(?!\.)
```

The lookbehind ensures that the string of digits does not begin with a `.`, so that something like `.5` won't be matched. The lookahead ensures that the string of digits does not end with a `.`, so that `5.` won't be matched.

Comment: Yes, `NSRegularExpression`s do support lookbehind and lookahead, this will work nicely. Encoded as a literal string the Objective-C code it will look like this: @"(?<!\\.)\\d+(?!\\.)".

Comment: Ohhh the tag is "*ns*regularexpression." I missed the ns-part on the first read.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to look for all digits, that don't have a "." in front, and have whitespace afterwards, like so:

```
[^\.]([0-9]+)\s
```

Comment: Two problems with this: the first character class consumes digits, and an integer that's not followed by white space, for example the last one, won't be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Could try this:

```
/(?:^|[^\.])(\d+)(?:\s+|$)/
```

Make sure a digit(s) does not start with a dot, or is the beginning of the string, and makes sure the digit(s) are followed by a space, or the end of the string.

Here is a PHP example in action:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:^|[^\.])(\d+)(?:\s+|$)/', '5 + 5.5 + 6 / 2.0 + 33 * 16', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
/* Var Dump:
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '5 ' (length=2)
      1 => string ' 6 ' (length=3)
      2 => string ' 33 ' (length=4)
      3 => string ' 16' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '5' (length=1)
      1 => string '6' (length=1)
      2 => string '33' (length=2)
      3 => string '16' (length=2)
*/
```

So what was captured was 5, 6, 33, and 16 (I added some longer digits to ensure it works)